Cannot install codemod?
I tried to run codemod through npx codemod react/findDOMNode --target src, however this gave an error. The same as the error I got when I tried to install the codemod package: (npm i g codemod)
npm error code EUNSUPPORTEDPROTOCOL
npm error Unsupported URL Type "catalog:": catalog:


If I try to open the igven logs this is what they contain:
0 verbose cli /Users/paulweijtens/.nvm/versions/node/v20.14.0/bin/node /Users/paulweijtens/.nvm/versions/node/v20.14.0/bin/npm
1 info using npm@10.8.2
2 info using node@v20.14.0
3 silly config load:file:/Users/paulweijtens/.nvm/versions/node/v20.14.0/lib/node_modules/npm/npmrc
4 silly config load:file:/Users/paulweijtens/.npmrc
5 silly config load:file:/Users/paulweijtens/.nvm/versions/node/v20.14.0/etc/npmrc
6 verbose title npm i codemod
7 verbose argv "i" "--global" "codemod"
8 verbose logfile logs-max:10 dir:/Users/paulweijtens/.npm/_logs/2024-07-16T14_48_56_456Z-
9 verbose logfile /Users/paulweijtens/.npm/_logs/2024-07-16T14_48_56_456Z-debug-0.log
10 silly packumentCache heap:4345298944 maxSize:1086324736 maxEntrySize:543162368
11 silly logfile start cleaning logs, removing 2 files
12 silly idealTree buildDeps
13 silly fetch manifest codemod@*
14 silly packumentCache full:https://registry.npmjs.org/codemod cache-miss
15 silly logfile done cleaning log files
16 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/codemod 731ms (cache revalidated)
17 silly packumentCache full:https://registry.npmjs.org/codemod set size:217441 disposed:false
18 silly placeDep ROOT codemod@0.11.29 OK for:  want: *
19 verbose stack Error: Unsupported URL Type "catalog:": catalog:
19 verbose stack     at unsupportedURLType (/Users/paulweijtens/.nvm/versions/node/v20.14.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-package-arg/lib/npa.js:310:15)
19 verbose stack     at fromURL (/Users/paulweijtens/.nvm/versions/node/v20.14.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-package-arg/lib/npa.js:367:13)
19 verbose stack     at Function.resolve (/Users/paulweijtens/.nvm/versions/node/v20.14.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-package-arg/lib/npa.js:83:12)
19 verbose stack     at /Users/paulweijtens/.nvm/versions/node/v20.14.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:1008:39
19 verbose stack     at run (/Users/paulweijtens/.nvm/versions/node/v20.14.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/promise-call-limit/dist/commonjs/index.js:67:22)
19 verbose stack     at /Users/paulweijtens/.nvm/versions/node/v20.14.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/promise-call-limit/dist/commonjs/index.js:84:9
19 verbose stack     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
19 verbose stack     at callLimit (/Users/paulweijtens/.nvm/versions/node/v20.14.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/promise-call-limit/dist/commonjs/index.js:35:69)
19 verbose stack     at #buildDepStep (/Users/paulweijtens/.nvm/versions/node/v20.14.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:1022:11)
19 verbose stack     at async Arborist.buildIdealTree (/Users/paulweijtens/.nvm/versions/node/v20.14.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:181:7)
20 error code EUNSUPPORTEDPROTOCOL
21 error Unsupported URL Type "catalog:": catalog:
22 silly unfinished npm timer reify 1721141336722
23 silly unfinished npm timer reify:loadTrees 1721141336724
24 silly unfinished npm timer idealTree:buildDeps 1721141336730
25 silly unfinished npm timer idealTree:#root 1721141336730
26 verbose cwd /Users/paulweijtens/Documents
27 verbose os Darwin 23.5.0
28 verbose node v20.14.0
29 verbose npm  v10.8.2
30 verbose exit 1
31 verbose code 1
32 error A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/paulweijtens/.npm/_logs/2024-07-16T14_48_56_456Z-debug-0.log

What is going on, why can I not do anything?

This is evidently a bug in codemod@0.11.29, released 3 hours ago as of writing.
npx codemod@0.11.28 react/findDOMNode --target src

doesn't raise that error.
EDIT: According to this comment by the Codemod people the broken release has been pulled now.

I reported this upstream: https://github.com/codemod-com/codemod/issues/1082
